# Better way to trim strength lengths in object than reflection

Tags: java, reflection, spring-data-jpa, annotations, java-11

I have a custom annotation defined for trimming strings based on the size specified.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Trim {
    public int size();
}
```

and an entity where I am using it

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Users {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Trim(size = 10)
    private String firstName;

    @Trim(size = 10)
    private String middleName;

    @Trim(size = 10)
    private String lastName;

    @Trim(size = 25)
    private String address;

}
```

The goal is to trim size based on what's specified in the annotation. For ex: the *address* column has a size constraint of 25 characters on the database table and if the *address* field contains more than 25 characters we need to trim the string to only consider the first 25 characters prior to calling `save()` on the entity. This can't be done in code because there are many fields with size constraints in many tables.

This is currently done through reflections and the function below works but I am wondering if there is a better way than this.

```
    public User trimStrings(User u) throws IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field f : u.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            if (f.get(u) != null && f.isAnnotationPresent(Trim.class)) {
                Trim t = f.getDeclaredAnnotation(Trim.class);
                String str = (String) f.get(u);
                int siz = Math.min(t.size(), str.length());
                f.set(u, str.substring(0, siz));
            }
            f.setAccessible(false);
        }
        return u;
    }
```

Comment: A small sidenote: Just about every major database offloads strings in a separate table, meaning: [A] they support any-len strings, and [B] adding a limit anyway (generally possible, to be backwards compatible with 1980s database design SQL) doesn't make things any faster. You probably simply don't need any of this stuff in the first place. And if you do, 'silently toss out a bunch of string data' is a really, really bad solution to the problem. __40 years ago__ that was okay - robust error handling was too complicated for e.g. a commodore 64 or whatnot. But today? Weird.

Comment: Second note, databases generally do the trimming for you; there is no need to do it java-side.

Comment: Thanks [@rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) for your response. I agree that's it's weird, the database table design isn't owned by me and I am only building the code. Re the database trimming, I considered that option too wasn't able to figure out how to generalize that. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean, 'generalize it'? You want to handroll a database abstraction system that is database engine agnostic? Hibernate is a project that does that. I think it's... a few hundred thousand personhours in at this point. What you're signing yourself up for is unbelievably complicated. Abort now. Give it all a bit of a rethink. There's usually nothing wrong with locking in the specific DB engine you're going to use, for example.

Comment: I didn't mean database agnostic. The `trimStrings()` function is generic enough to accept an object and trim strings of every field that is annotated with `@Trim`, so there's no separate business logic to handle this except for the annotation itself. If we were to do this on the database side, for ex: MySQL how can this be done in a generic without having to write a check for every field?

Comment: I don't think there is a 'better' way than what you have. I don't see any particularly good use cases for the concept, though. There's the obvious one, of replicating the mistakes of SQL design of the mid 80s. If that's your intent - I think what you have will work fine. Just giving you the headsup that it's not exactly modern style these days. You know the project better than I do, no doubt :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot actually, silently cutting strings never was okay. Even for those old systems. If such a limitation exists, it should be shown at the input side already (and back in the days, input masks usually had such indicators). Or, if a bulk correction is needed, there should be a report about the affected entries.

Comment: Sure you could build a graph of `MethodHandle`s - which can probably be better optimized. But that code will even look much more complicated than what you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `@PostLoad` annotation inside entity classes.

```
 @PostLoad
public void trim(){
}
```

You can either write in here trim for fields you want. Or you still can use reflection, but you don't have to call it manually, it will be called by JPA when entity loaded. Or you can put this in a superclass and all classes that need trim to extends this.

You can find a nice explanation in here for JPA entity lifecycle :  https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events